# How to disable day of the week in extended taskbar on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, time, date

So I have small taskbar buttons and I want to have date and hour on the taskbar. I unlock my taskbar and I extend it just a little but it doesn't show hour and date first but skips to date, hour and day of the week. Here are some pictures to explain my situation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Open Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Region and change the Format of Long Date use dd/MMMM/yyyy and Short Date dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Take a look at [Customize Date in Taskbar](http://winaero.com/blog/customize-the-taskbar-date-and-time-formats-in-windows-10/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately after doing what you've said it still shows up the same way it did before.

Comment: can you show in the comment the format of Short and Long Date?

Comment: Maybe a screenshot of Clock, Language, and Region\Region

Comment: Try [This Link](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-date-and-time-formats-windows-10)

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/ac4b046941966581ada7e741fca7251c.png But everything is still the same way as I extend the taskbar, it immediatelly goes to day of the week, hour and date

Comment: if you change it maybe you need to restart the computer in order to apply the changes it depends of your computer

Comment: I am really sorry to say that, but unfortunately nothing's changed. I feel like I'm missing some settings, but whenever I check, everything seems right. Yet it isn't.

Answer (score -2):

Hopefully you've resolved this by now but for anyone else having this problem, all you need to do is drag the toolbar's edge up/down to reduce it. Doing so should change the clock display from day/date/time to just time.